# Shipping rates not displaying correctly - using Matrixrate from WebshopApps

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

Using Free version of Matrixrate for shipping rates outside of UK. Rates are calculated based on Country and Weight (with 7 weight bands). For example...

- shipping a 150g item to the France should cost £3.50
- ...and so on up to 12kg
- shipping a 12kg item to the France should cost £43.50
- shipping a 150g item to US should cost £3.75
- ...and so on up to 12kg
- shipping a 12kg item to US should cost £47.50

However, shipping rates for all countries are returned as per the lowest weight item. So the 12kg item going to the US is £3.75 instead of £30.

My spreadsheet is set up as per the image below. Am I missing any columns?[image]

Comment: Use webshop app matrix rate may resolve your problem its also free.

Comment: Thanks Aman. MatrixRate is the shipping extension from WebshopApps

Comment: Then there need some customization you should check this file `WebShopApps\MatrixRate\Model\ResourceModel\Carrier\Matrixrate`  `getRate` method you are able to figure out where the problem is creating.

Comment: Thanks - all sorted now. It was a CSV formatting issue!!!

Comment: How do you find? @user69135

Comment: @Ranganathan Did you solve the issue?